# Had to increase http.globalAgent.maxSockets for iOS simulator, but why?

Tags: node.js, ios-simulator

I have a proxy server built in nodejs. It was working fine, until I tried browsing the web through it via the iOS iPhone simulator. Then it would load a few requests and hang indefinitely.

I narrowed it down to this:

```
var req = http.request({...}, function(){
  // this is not being called for some requests
})
```

...which in turn let me to discover this:

```
req.on('socket', function(){
  // this is not being called for some requests
})
```

Suspecting [trouble with pooling of sockets](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent), I set `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 50` and that indeed fixed it. (The default is 5.) But I feel like I've only fixed the symptom of a deeper problem. It only happened when I browsed from within the iOS simulator, via xcode. Using desktop Chrome, not in the simulator but using that same proxy instance, there were no problems.

Comment: have you tested on iphone devices?

Comment: @Joiningss - Yes, I had run quite a bit of traffic through the proxy from a physical iPhone and didn't notice a problem.